# Why C# .Net Core RestClient return cryptic response. Postman returns readable json

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman, rest-client

I have a Postman call that successfully returns readable response, such as:

[image]

Now, I want to execute the same call via C# and .Net Core RestClient. Postman has an option to generate a code snippet for different languages, here is an example for C#:

[image]

But when executing it, within my C# app, I receive an error with response, instead of the same Postman response with valid result:

[image]

How come?

Comment: have you tried to convert it from base64?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you try to JSON de-serialize an XML response anyway

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was a code copy paste mistake, nevertheless, in the image we still see the cryptic response content, should I convert it from Base64 than, as ingvar suggested. I will try that. Does that mean that Postman converts Base64 responses by default?

Comment: You were right @ingvar, I have decoded the string, it returned an error for some reson, I will update the question

Comment: well it looks like you are sending in weird stuff. Why are you sending "undefined"<Xml>.... That looks like the response form the postman call. Seems like a cut n paste error

Comment: well, what you see in C# code is all purely generated by Postman. It is all working fine inside Postman, wnd within the Postman there is a way to get C# version of the call, so I did, copy pasye, and in my opinion it should work, but it is not, trying to find why not, without customizing it too much

Comment: From the response, it looks like you are missing a header X-EBAY-API-DETA... your image cuts it off there. I don't see anything in you code that is adding that header. Also, if you are sending ebay xml, what makes you think they are going to respond with json?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you are right, at this point I have fixed the HEADER related issues. But still the question is why Postman worked, and once translated into C# code, it does not. Postman did not need the HEADERS we see in the error

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm grossly misunderstanding, you're getting `xml` when you want `json` and the headers visible in screenshots are the only headers on the request?

It sure looks like you want to specify the `Accept` header.

`Accept:application/json`

*Further Reading*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept